# Npm, Dev dependecy or dependecy, when packing everything into one script using webpack etc?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, gulp

When for example with webpack we pack everything into a single js file, it already imports dependencies to that file. in that case, do we need any dependency in `package.json`, or they can be all `--save-dev`?

Please consider that I only talk about front end development and implementation.

Cheers

Comment: Could you provide an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your app gets deployed or distributed. Regular dependencies are what the app needs at runtime. Something is a dev dependency when it is only required in order to make changes to the app.

If the webpack build has to run before the app can be used (e.g. in a continuous integration environment, where the app is built as part of the test & deploy process), then anything required at build time is a 'regular' dependency. In this case most of your packages will be regular dependencies.

If you are building the app once and the built assets are what gets distributed/deployed -- so the build does not have to be done again before the app can be used -- then anything required at build time is a 'dev' dependency, because someone using your code should not have to build again unless they are making changes to the app. In this case most of your dependencies will be 'dev' dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Does not matter where the dependencies are (i mean, devDependencies or normal dependencies). What webpack is going to look at are the `require`and `import` statements in your source code.

When devDependencies and dependencies make a real difference, is when you publish a pack. devdependencies would just be installed if you run manually `npm/yarn install` on this package. If your user is installing this package, when one runs `npm install --save-dev yourpackagename` only the dependencies that were in the `dependencies` field are going to be intalled.

TL;TR: 
No, webpack does not care for where your dependencies are on `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks Matheus, while your answer is true, but I think Brendan's answer helped me to clear my mind.